# GitHub Pages and Relative Paths: <base> element didn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, github-pages, stenciljs

I made a stenciljs component and tried to host it on GitHub pages, but ran into issues with (I think) relative paths. I did get some functionality by changing the `<script>` source to include the repo name, but then the issue was the other paths within the code itself (ie. `<img src=relative/path/to/img>`). I tried to add `<base href="/[repo]/">` in `<head>` but it didn't seem to work. Just curious what's up, thanks!

Comment: Is it an app generated by Stencil or just one that imports the components?

Comment: just imported the components, not even imported actually, just grabbed the `dist` folder from the stencil build and copied and pasted it into another folder.